# staggering animations seamlessly with css animation-delay

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I am working on a CSS animation and I have run into a problem when trying to add an event to add some dynamic animations to the page.

To make it simple, here is the looping animation for a "sky" div:

```
.sky {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-animation: animation-sky 30s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation-sky{
0%, 100% {background-color: rgb(53, 110, 231);}
16% {background-color: skyblue;}
21% {background-color: orange;}
31% {background-color: rgb(19, 2, 61);}
77% {background-color: rgb(19, 2, 61);}
82% {background-color: orange;}
92% {background-color: skyblue;}
}
```

As you can see, it loops between colors, corresponding to the time of day.

Then, using a jQuery event listener bound to a button, I add an "animating" class to the body to loop to a new animation:

```
    .animating .sky {
    -webkit-animation: scene2-sky 38s linear 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 22s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scene2-sky{
        0% {background-color: rgb(19, 2, 61);}
        100% {background-color: rgb(19, 2, 61);}

}
```

I add a delay to the animation because I have other parts that need to finish before displaying the background color in the keyframes.

My problem is that instead of delaying the animation (like I gave it of 22 sec), it just turns the background color to white until the 22 seconds are up.

Is there any way to have it continue the previous animation until the animation-delay queues the "animating" one to start?

Here's a link to jsfiddle for clarification: http://jsfiddle.net/benjtinsley/UDzh7/

Comment: Green sky? You're based on Neptune, I see :) Look here http://desandro.github.io/motion-emotion/ for cyclic color animations, maybe that brings you forward. It's explained by David DeSandro who brought us Masonry, Isotope and Packery into the world of jQuery magic.

Comment: Please clean up your fiddle, nobody can help you like that.
You can include jQuery in left frame under "Frameworks & Extensions", there is no need to directly paste it in your JS frame.

Answer (score 0):

A given element can have only a value for a property.

When you set the value for the property "animation", you override whatever value that porperty had. The fact that the new animation value has a delay doesn't alter that fact.

To acomplish what you want, just set the delay in the jQuery function that sets the new class to the element